# How to Set the MTU(Maximum Transmission unit) in NS2?

Tags: ns2

I am using NS2 simulator for  doing some network simulation and having some problem while setting the MTU value ie maximum transmission unit. I want know what is the default value of MTU in NS2 and how can i change this value according to my need?
I want to set different MTU value to observe the behaviour of TCP in different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](http://aloksen.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-set-mtu-value-in-ns2.html) :

> Default value of MTU(MaximumTransmission Unit) in ns2 is generally
>   1500. Now to change this value according to your research, just go to
>   file "mac-802.3.h" and change the value of "IEEE_8023_MAXFRAME" and
>   compile it once again. You can find this file in

```
/home/username/ns-allinone-2.xx/ns-2.xx/mac
```

> To know more about MTU and to know what it actually is just visit the following link :

http://www.pointless.net/~jasper/consume/docs/my-docs/mtu.html